# Apparent IO.Ports.SerialPort Flaw in C# or Possible Hardware Flaw

Tags: c#, serial-port, visual-studio-debugging

Please forgive me as this is going to be quite a long post. I'm currently using the SerialPort class in C# to write an application to communicate with a device called a Fluke 5500A. I've, in the past, had many problems as the amount of time the device takes to issue a command and return whatever it outputs in unpredictable at best. I asked a question yesterday here: [System.Timers.Timer Usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17661881/system-timers-timer-usage) The answer to the question is wonderful and most of the time appears to work perfectly. As an example my the class I use to connect to a SerialPort now looks like this:

```
public class SerialPortConnection
{
    private SerialPort serialPort;
    private string ping;
    double failOut;
    bool isReceiving;

    public SerialPortConnection(string comPort = "Com1", int baud = 9600, System.IO.Ports.Parity parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None, int dataBits = 8, System.IO.Ports.StopBits stopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One, string ping = "*IDN?", double failOut = 2)
    {
        this.ping = ping;
        this.failOut = failOut * 1000;

        try
        {
            serialPort = new SerialPort(comPort, baud, parity, dataBits, stopBits);
            serialPort.NewLine = ">";
            serialPort.ReadTimeout = 1000;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            serialPort = null;
        }
    }

    //Open Serial Connection. Returns False If Unable To Open.
    public bool OpenSerialConnection()
    {
        //Opens Initial Connection:
        try
        {
            serialPort.Open();
            serialPort.Write("REMOTE\r");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }

        serialPort.Write(ping + "\r");
        var testReceived = "";

        try
        {
            testReceived += serialPort.ReadLine();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public string WriteSerialConnection(string SerialCommand)
    {
        serialPort.Write(String.Format(SerialCommand + "\r"));
        var received = "";

        try
        {
            received += serialPort.ReadLine();
            return received;
        }
        catch
        {
            received = "Error: No Data Received From Device";
            return received;
        }
    }

    public bool CloseSerialConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            serialPort.Write("LOCAL\r");
            serialPort.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, when I open the a connection to, in this case, `Com1` I test the connection by writing a command `*IDN?` to the SerialPort. The return for this command looks like so:

```
FLUKE,5500A,8030005,2.61+1.3+2.0+*
66>
```

In the class I've set `">"` as the NewLine property so that SerialPort.ReadLine() doesn't finish till it finds that token. I've never once had the class itself throw an exception but I've noticed while debugging that sometimes `testReceived` won't catch that returned data properly, despite the fact that no exceptions are thrown and the code continues executing properly, and instead `received` will catch the returned string:

```
FLUKE,5500A,8030005,2.61+1.3+2.0+*
66>
```

whenever I pass my first command via `SerialPort.Write();` Something important to know is that commands can be executed without that data being fully returned. My concern is that the initial `ReadLine()` appears to be skipping past that occasionally without catching the entire return. My thought is that there's an inherent flaw in the device I'm communicating with causing this but I'd prefer to be entirely sure before continuing.

My command order looks like so:

First I submit a command on startup:

```
REMOTE
```

This disables interaction with the device's manual interface and allows me to submit commands via the Serial Port.

Then I issue `*IDN?`, in this case, to check that the device is connected:

```
*IDN?
```

If nothing is return, the application is set to display an error in a message box and then `FailFast`. If all goes well a command can be submitted like so:

```
STBY
OUT 30MV,60HZ
OPER
```

The only command submitted here manually is `OUT 30,MV,60HZ`. `STBY` and `OPER` are set in the app.config as they only add an unnecessary step to the usage of the application. The `STBY` command puts the machine in standby for safety reasons. The `OPER` command puts it in operating mode and the device begins operating under the set parameters.

The application then waits for a technician to enter a result into a textbox and submit it. The content of these results aren't particularly pertinent but upon hitting the result button the machine is put back in standby:

```
STBY
```

Finally, two more commands are submitted when the application is closed:

```
*RST
LOCAL
```

First `*RST` resets the machine to ensure that it's in the same state as when it was powered on (I.E. It's not operating and no parameters are set). Then `LOCAL` sets the re-enables the manual interface for user interaction and disables access via the Serial Port till `REMOTE` is issued once more.

As you can see, a command is issued after `*IDN?` and before the first manual command that's sent (In this case we assume the command is `OUT 30MV,60HZ`). The problem is, sometimes I receive the output of `*IDN` whenever I check what the output of `OUT 30MV,60HZ` is yet I can see no problems within my code or the procedure I'm using to operate the machine. Is there any reason this could be happening?

As I've said, the error is extremely hard to reproduce (I've seen it twice in maybe forty runs). Even so, any error at all of this type is not acceptable in a production environment and the error needs to be fixed before I can begin testing my application in its entirety. I'll keep trying to reproduce the error so I can provide an example and hopefully provide further clarification as to what the problem might be.

EDIT:

I'd also like to clarify that I'm fairly certain the bug is not located somewhere within my application itself as the code is somewhat simplistic in nature:

```
public string SubmitCommand()
    {
        if (_command_Input != "No further commands to input.")
        {
            string received;
            serialPort.WriteSerialConnection("STBY");
            received = serialPort.WriteSerialConnection(_command_Input);
            serialPort.WriteSerialConnection("OPER");

            //Controls Enabled:
            _input_IsEnabled = false;
            _user_Input_IsEnabled = true;
            _results_Input_IsEnabled = false;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Input_IsEnabled");
            RaisePropertyChanged("User_Input_IsEnabled");
            RaisePropertyChanged("Results_Input_IsEnabled");

            return received;
        }
        else
            return "";
    }
```

received is then manipulated like so:

```
public bool SetOutput()
    {
        string inter1 = SubmitCommand();

        try
        {

            string[] lines = inter1.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray()).ToArray();
            _results_Changed = lines[2];
            RaisePropertyChanged("Results_Changed");
        }
        catch
        {
            _results_Changed = inter1;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Results_Changed");
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I can provide further code if need be but I can't currently see any other code that might be pertinent to the question at hand.

Comment: How can you be sure that the flaw doesn't exist on the device?

Comment: @BradRem That's why I'm asking. I'm unsure if it's a device flaw but that's much harder (if not impossible) to troubleshoot than a programming flaw. I'd like to be sure it's not a flaw somewhere in my code or in the SerialPort class before I continue on trying to troubleshoot it.

Comment: Compared to the Win32 Communications API it uses, `IO.Ports.SerialPort` is terribly broken.  I've had trouble myself, and seen reports from others concerning various problems, all of which went away after switching to use Win32 directly.

Comment: @BenVoigt So there's a good chance it's a direct bug in `IO.Ports.SerialPort` then and not a hardware flaw?

Comment: BTW, your code is not at all robust.  When `ReadLine` times out, it doesn't look like you have any recovery logic to get back in sync.

Comment: @BradRem I'm also forced to assume currently that it's not a hardware flaw as that still doesn't explain why the application continues executing as if `">"` has been found by `ReadLine()` and yet the return string isn't properly caught by `ReadLine()`.

Comment: @Zach: It's not so much that `IO.Ports.SerialPort` is buggy, as poor design.  It forces you to take a stupid approach, calling non-essential configuration APIs during open, using threadpool threads to receive events, having to then synchronize data across threads, not allowing inter-character timeouts.  Which makes it very difficult to use correctly.

Comment: BTW, what do you think `catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }` is doing?  In case you aren't familiar with exception handling, that block is *totally useless*.

Comment: @BenVoigt I realize it's useless. It's a remnant of the code I was using before. I've not removed it as I've been focused on trying to fix the issue I'm encountering.

Comment: @BenVoigt Originally I was writing exceptions to a console because I was having a multitude of other problems. It's just something that needs to be removed.

Comment: @Zach Smith I think you're misinterpreting what Ben is saying. When you call ReadLine() and it seemingly "skips" output that you thought should have been there, it's likely that it never encountered your NewLine character and all of that data is still on the buffer. If your NewLine finally streams in, the next time you call ReadLine() you're going to get the previously issued commands output, and now you're off sync. Either check to see that ReadLine() returns something useful or delay until you're sure the buffer is filled.

Comment: @glace: He says he never gets a `TimeoutException` though.  Although I do wonder what happens if there's a `>` in the receive buffer, or just being transmitted from the device, when his program starts.

Comment: My mistake, I missed the line where ReadTimeout was set to non 0.

Comment: @glace `ReadLine()` should always be checking for `">"` or waiting till the read times out. If the read times out the method returns `False` and `FailFast` is enabled. I wouldn't be encountering this error if it wasn't encountering `">"`.

Comment: Have you tried using a terminal program and just typing the commands to see what happens?

Comment: @dbasnett I've tried running the commands in a terminal and everything functions fine. The return looks exactly the same as I posted in my question. `66>` is a prompt showing that the buffer is finished being written to and the device is ready to accept another command.

Comment: Do you receive the command prompt after every command?  What version of .Net are you using?  My experience with the SerialPort was bad prior to 3.5.  Since then I have had no problems that I can recall, especially since 4.0.

Comment: @dbasnett `">"` is received after every command I issue. That's constant to my knowledge (there could be fairly obscure commands I'm not using but those aren't pertinent). I am currently using WPF and .Net 4.0.

Comment: I'm going to start dumping every bit of info I possibly can from the class into a log file. I'll add that to the question as it might provide some clarification. Thanks everyone for your time.

Comment: When working with serial equipment it is not guaranteed you will always get the response you are looking for, every magnetic field can alter and damage communication. that being said - if the problem is not from the flow of the code - it probably is related to timing between calls.
To really answer question you need to describe when is it not working - "sometimes" imply more to a hardware related problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made this hard to diagnose, the response you don't like looks *exactly* like the one you do like.

In general, you need to ensure that your program is in sync with the device.  A possible failure mode is when the driver still has unread data in the receive buffer from a previous connection.  Stale data could also exist in the device's transmit buffer.  When you start back up, you'll read that stale data and assume it was a response to your command.  It wasn't.  You'll now be permanently out of sync, always reading stale data that was the response to the previous command.

It is also rather odd that this works without taking care of handshaking, device normally *do* pay attention to that.

To avoid accidents, initialize your program like this:

- Call the Open() method to open the port
- Set the RtsEnable and DtrEnable properties to true so that the device always sees a good signal that allows it to transmit data
- Sleep for about 100 msec to allow the device to send any data that it still had buffered from the previous connection but could not send because the handshake was off
- Call DiscardInBuffer() to throw away any stale response bytes.

You have now a reasonable guarantee you'll be in sync.

Comment: Connecting to the device doesn't call for a handshake. I don't know the reasoning behind that but I do know the device is rather old and the programmer's manual that came with the device doesn't mention handshaking for RS-232. I've noticed it calls for handshaking on IEEE-488 but that functions differently and its usage isn't an option as the company I work for would prefer not to use it.

Comment: However I don't know much about how this should function as I've never worked with SerialPorts before. I'll try what you've mentioned.